# extend gnome-shell PATH for access to ruby binary with RVM

Tags: linux, bash, gnome, ruby, rvm

I have a terminal written in ruby that I install with a gem. I want to be able to launch this terminal when I hit `Alt+F2` in gnome-shell. When I used the ruby version of my system, I just have to modify my *.profile* like this:

```
PATH=$PATH:$(ruby -e "print Gem.user_dir")/bin
```

But with RVM, it does not work because the ruby used is the system ruby binary.
How can I get the current rvm gem path from this *.profile* file ?